# execute code on project Creation

Tags: tfs

I wonder if there is a way to make Team Foundation Server to execute a code when creating a new project.

The objective is that when the project is created TFS could write in the SharePoint portal for the project the url of the tfs portal.

Some one knows a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do this but here is a useful [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/26/extend-team-projects-and-team-explorer-in-tfs-2010.aspx) which has some details and code sample to extend the team project creation wizard.